# Find nearest object in 2D - can it be optimised below O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Imagine 2D plane with n objects. Pick any point on the plane and find which object is the nearest.

The obvious solution is to calculate the distance from selected point to all n objects and choose the shortest distance but isn't there more optimal algorithm? Something like a binary tree, some way to smartly divide the plane into areas etc?

**EDIT:** let's assume that those points "do not move" and that we will have to find the nearest object many times. In other words we can sort the objects into some structure right at the beginning if we want.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on input `data structure`. If you are getting points with no order (probably a simple array), you of course need to iterate all of them.

Comment: Sort everything in a maintained quad tree.

Comment: maybe a approximate answer suit your requirement. check out `Approximate nearest neighbor` such as [Locality-sensitive_hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing#LSH_algorithm_for_nearest_neighbor_search)

Comment: This is known as the post office problem. With suitable preprocessing taking time O(n Log(n)) and O(n) storage, queries can be answered in time O(Log(n)), for isolated points. There are several techniques to achieve this result in the worst case or in the expected case. But the best choice may depend on what you call an "object".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the world of games programming, the idea of "Space Partitioning" is commonly used to optimise code for things like collision detection.

A very simple explanation goes as follows. You start off with your objects in your 2D space:

[image: Points in space]

And you use an algorithm to divide up the space to make "buckets" of objects which are close together:

[image: Partitioned space]

Now when you want to compute "which object is closest to a point" you only need test the ones which are in adjacent buckets:

[image: Tests]

If you choose your partitioning algorithm with care, this can make for a significant speed-up, because you test many fewer points for closeness.

There are loads of algorithms for how you can partition up the space your objects live in, and they can be based on arrays or a variety of types of trees. I see while I have been typing this that [Tommy's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154450/find-nearest-object-in-2d-can-it-be-optimised-below-on/28155167#28155167) has listed out a few of the common ones.

There are lots of write-ups of this concept on the internet, since it's a fairly commonly used pattern. This is one I read in the past:

http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html

Answer (score 2):

There are probably hundreds of solutions better than O(n).

A k-d tree or a quadtree are amongst the most well-known. There are also solutions that involve merely a sorted list, which tend to be more applicable to moving objects but are also generally simpler.

**Quadtree**

A quadtree is a tree structure where each node is a rectangle with four children. The four children are a subdivision of the original. Supposing you were inserting points only, at each node the test would be:

1. does this node have children? If so:

   1. which child does the point lie within?
   2. recurse to that child.
2. If not:

   1. add point at this node.
   2. check out how many points are now stored at this node.
   3. if it's now too many then create children and push each points to the appropriate child.

You can divide the node into equally-sized children or attempt approximately to follow the distribution of points, e.g. taking the average x and average y as the split locations.

If you're storing whole objects then styles vary on whether you insert into every node that overlaps the object and whether the children therefore  mutually overlap a little at the edges. If you know a maximum object size then that's often the way to go since the object you're testing against at runtime will only ever have to consider exactly one leaf node. Otherwise you'll have to consider the union of several nodes.

Otherwise searching means finding the leaf node your point is in, getting the least distance from that, then walking back up the tree until your test point is further from the relevant child boundary than the least distance currently known. At that point you know you're definitely not going to find anything closer.

**k-d tree**

A k-d tree is also a tree structure but is strictly a binary tree. Each node is a 1d span and a dividing point. Child nodes are spans on a different axis.

E.g. one node might know it contains all points for x in [0, 10). It will record that its children know only about points for x in [0, 7) and x in [7, 10). However its two children nodes will be phrased in terms of y. So e.g. the left one may know that it covers y in [0, 6) and its children cover y in [0, 1) and [2, 6).

The psuedo code for insertion test is therefore identical to that given for quadtrees above though the specific tests are different. Taking an average of x or an average of y when deciding where to split is much more common. The same comments about permitting children to overlap apply.

Searching follows the same tree-walking logic as the quadtree.

**Sorted List**

For argument's sake let's say you're sorting on x alone. There's a single list of all objects sorted by their lowest x extent. You know the width of every object.

To find out which object is closest to a point, first find the index at which that object would be inserted in the list. It's sorted so you can do that in O(log n) time.

Work out the distance from your point to the object at that insertion index. That's then an upper bound for the furthest an object can be. That upper bound dictates how far you need ever possibly need to search left or right in the list. Go left and right simultaneously, updating the upper bound until your iterators are now further away just on the x axis than the upper bound. Then the upper bound is exactly the right answer.